# How do I get a list of items purchasable/purchased from Playstore for IAP in Android?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-purchase

I am using IAP to purchase images in android.
I need to display the all items or the items not purchased by the user when initiate the IAP.
The user can click the required item and then the IAP process continuous for payment.
How can i make this, friends?
Can you give an example for this?

Comment: have a look at docs: `http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html`

Comment: thanks for your reply friend, but i don't know the name of the products, ie., in feature i released my app after that i added some new images to in app products at that time what can i do ? is there any way to get the items list without knowing item names(dynamically getting item list )?

Comment: the basic purpose of in-app is to provide extended features after purchasing particular product.if you are going to add in-app products in future,how will you code your app to provide extended features on purchasing those particular products?

Comment: i have to show list which have the In-app products stored in google play store to purchase for users , from that list user can purchase any of the product

Comment: ok.post your code,I will suggest you the changes accordingly

Comment: And here is a [clickable documentation link](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my question 
i get the list of products from my local server and i stored it ArrayList.
Then i used that to retrieve the list of products from playstore